# How to run make_server from the simple_server in python on multiprocess?

Tags: python, apache, webserver, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have one simple program of wsgi.

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import time

def application(environ, start_response):
    response_body = 'Hello World'
    status = '200 OK'

    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    if environ['PATH_INFO'] != '/favicon.ico':

        print "Time :", int(time.time())
        if int(time.time()) % 2:
            print "Even"
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            print "Odd"
    return [response_body]

httpd = make_server('localhost', 8000, application)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

So as per the code if the `timestamp` is `Even` then it will send response after 10 second. But if the `timestamp` is `Odd` then it will send response directly without sleep.

So my question is if i will send 2 request and if first request will send the request in `Even` mode then my second request will be serve after completing first one.

I check the solution and found that 'multiprocess`can solve this problem. I set the apache configuration with`multiprocess`. Then I get the response for`Odd`without completing`Even` request.

I check how to set the `multiprocess` with `make_server` method of `simple_server` module. When I run the `python /usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py` I get the output and last few lines are

```
wsgi.errors = <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7f22ba2a1270>
wsgi.file_wrapper = <class wsgiref.util.FileWrapper at 0x1647600>
wsgi.input = <socket._fileobject object at 0x1569cd0>
wsgi.multiprocess = False
wsgi.multithread = True
wsgi.run_once = False
wsgi.url_scheme = 'http'
wsgi.version = (1, 0)
```

So I was search how to set this `make_server` multiprocess so make_server can handle more then 1 request if any request is in progress.

Thx in advance.

Comment: simple_server is a toy in python if you want true concurrency look into Tornado, Twisted or Pyramid

Comment: I want to create one webservice in SOAP. So I just install soaplib 2.0 and using that functionality to expose my service. So when I am processing one request I have to wait to server second request if I will run the server with `make_server` so I think make_server is not supporting multiprocess am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Apache/mod_wsgi than you don't need the `make_server/serve_forever` stuff. Apache will handle that for you (as it is the web server). It will handle the processes and run the `application` callback function.

Make sure your Apache and mod_wsgi configuration allows multiprocess/multithread. Good reference is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading)

Comment: Thx Secator. If I use Apache then its work but I want to use simple_server as multiprocess that is possible or not?